# If I write an add-in for office 2007 will it work for 2010, 2013?

Tags: c#, add-in, office-2007, office-2010, office-2013

I am currently in the process of re-writing some VBA macros that were written for office 2003. I was wondering if I wrote a C# add-in for 2007, if it would work for 2010 or maybe even 2013. Or if I wrote them for 2010 if they would work for 2007 and 2013 as well. I currently have access to 2007 but I could get access to 2010 if need be, no 2013 yet.

So, basically, how much does the version of office affect the plugins?

Comment: [Excel Addin that works on Excel 2007 and 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937891/62576) might help.

Comment: [This][1] might address your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218488/vsto-2003-2010-add-in-compatibility

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use **Visual Studio Tools for Office 2010 (VSTO 4.0)** then it will compatible for `Office 2007 ,Office 2010 and with Office 2013`.If you use earlier version other than the above then you can use that only for particular office versions only.As a example `VSTO 3.0` only supports `office 2003 and 2007` as shown below table.

For more information check this out [**Visual Studio Tools for Office**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSTO) and [**Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=44074)

compatibility Shows like below:

[image]

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Sampath. I was wondering where it says that the VSTO 4.0 supports 2013? I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officedevpreview/thread/7c928b03-82a7-4399-bac2-d7fe6154fc5f/), but I was wondering where you found yours?

Comment: @Natzely Yes. Actually it's there on my 2nd link under "Prerequisites:" section.Anyway Glad to hear that it helped!

Comment: Second link as mentioned is now broken.

Answer (score 5):

you can take a look at [Netoffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com), a wrapper for MS Office that enables you to create Addins for all supported versions of MS Office. You don't need VSTO and you can check within your own code which version of Office your AddIn is running in.

Comment: Just downloaded that and it looks great.  Seems to avoid most of VSTOs problems.