# Forward Compatibility of Office Addins

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, excel-addins, excel-2013

I have built an add-in for office 2010 using VS 2010. I have followed [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) to create the msi but when I tried to install it with office 2013 I get an error telling me that:

> "A required component for interacting with excel is not available..."

Do I need to link to office 2013 assemblies to deploy for office 2013?

**EDIT:** It says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783379/if-i-write-an-add-in-for-office-2007-will-it-work-for-2010-2013) that using VSTO V4 should make it compatible but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have yourself created a Windows Installer Launcher condition that produces the mentioned error, following the mentioned tutorial. You should remove the condition that checks for the particluar PIA component by Component ID.

[image: Condiotions to remove]

Rather than check and produce false errors, add VSTO and PIA as a prerequisite and you can also include it in your setup:

[image]

You will have to [download Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies Bootstrapper Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18249) and install it on your development machine.
This enables you to add PIA 2010 as a prerequisite in setup project, which is what you need.

Also if you need to include PIA 2010 within your installation, you will have to copy
[Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18249) (all the extracted files) to
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Office2010PIARedist`.

Your setup will then look something like this:

[image]

No, you do not need to link 2013 PIA to make your solution work in Office 2013, VSTO and PIA 2010 should work with Excel 2013 - but the extra functionality of Excel 2013 app is naturally missing there. But you would need to upgrade to VS 2012 or 2013 if you would like to use [VSTO 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2013/03/06/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-now-available.aspx).

**So you can keep using VSTO 2010 for Office 2013.**

[But also look at this article.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-quot-lights-up-quot-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx)

> **When you compile an add-in project that targets the .NET Framework 4,
>   by default the type information for all the PIA types referenced in
>   the add-in code is embedded in the add-in assembly.** At run time, this
>   type information is used to resolve calls to the underlying COM type,
>   rather than relying on type information in the PIAs.

So after all it means that if you target .NET 4 you do not have to worry about PIA on a target computer at all. So you also do not need to add Microsoft Office 2010 PIA as a prerequisite. Still you will need VSTO runtime prerequisite.

Just check, that you reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` has the correct version and `EmbedInteropTypes` set to `true`:

[image]

This is a really good reason to delete those `Search for Office 2010 Shared PIA` conditions.

---

Remark: It seems that the problematic Windows Installer Launcher condition works when I enter [another component ID form here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937%28v=office.12%29.aspx#VSTO3SolutionPart1_DeployingVisualStudioToolsfortheOfficesystem30solutions), namely {FAB10E66-B22C-4274-8647-7CA1BA5EF30F}. It is Office 2007 component ID. I have tested it with Office 2007 and Office 2013 and both setups proceeded without any error and the add-in is working.