# Outlook Add-in 2010

Tags: c#, .net

I have created an add -in for outlook using Outlook add-in 2010, but i want it to work the same in Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2013 as it is in Outlook 2013. I created a ribbon and a custom menu, these functionalities are working fine in Outlook 2010.
But in Outlook 2007 ribbons are not getting displayed(even the Add in tag is not visible) but menu is working fine and in Outlook 2013, menu is not displayed but ribbon is working fine.

Is there any compatibility issues while using Outlook add-in 2010?

I used visual studio 2010 (.net framework 4).

Please provide a solution for this.

I need to write an outlook add-in which is supported in 2007/2010/2013.

Comment: I don't think it has issues. May be you could post your code skeleton for better understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I write an add-in for office 2007 will it work for 2010, 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783379/if-i-write-an-add-in-for-office-2007-will-it-work-for-2010-2013)

Comment: @sangeetha which version of VSTO youre using ...?

Comment: @sangeetha share some code for better understanding..1

Comment: @dashar I am all new to Outlook add-in.

Comment: Just wrote a sample menu code and ribbon similar to this.[link](http://www.ecanarys.com/blog-entry/building-outlook-2010-add-using-cnet-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Everything is working fine in Outlook 2010 but not as expected with 2007 and 2013